# Verify bitcoin address and amount from sign transaction

Tags: transactions

Is there a way i can extract the fromAddress, toAddress, amount and fees from a bitcoin sign transaction?

eg: `SignTransactionValue = signAddress(fromAddress, toAddress, amount, fees, privateKey)`

How can i extract back fromAddress, toAddress, amount and fees from the signTransactionValue?

Comment: What does `signAddress` produce? What do you mean by `SignTransactionValue`? This is not standard terminology and could mean many different things.